# std::string.c_str() causes access violation 0xC0000005

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, unicode, crypto++

I have a problem with crypto++ 5.6.4 (VS2010) exception.code throws an exception in RSaVerifyVector function (in decoder.Put line):

```
 bool RsaVerifyVector(const std::string&  publicKeyStrHex, const std::string& source, const std::vector<char>& sign)
    {
        CryptoPP::HexDecoder decoder;
        decoder.Put( (byte*)publicKeyStrHex.c_str(), publicKeyStrHex.size() );//-->>HERE IT THROWS Exception
        decoder.MessageEnd();

        CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey publicKey;
        publicKey.Load( decoder );

        // Verifier object
        CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PSS, CryptoPP::SHA1>::Verifier verifier( publicKey );

        std::vector<char> rawSignature;
        std::string signStr(utils::GetBeginOf(sign), sign.size());
        utils::FromHexString(utils::string2wstring(signStr), &rawSignature);
        // Verify
        const char * pData = utils::GetBeginOf(source);
        return verifier.VerifyMessage( (const byte*) pData,
            source.size(), (const byte*) utils::GetBeginOf(rawSignature), rawSignature.size() );
    }
```

Help me to find a cause of this exception please! Exception attached. Thank you very much.

[image]

When exception occurs, after it shows me a cryptlib.h file and the following line of code:

```
template <class T>
    void GetRequiredParameter(const char *className, const char *name, T &value) const
    {
        if (!GetValue(name, value))
            throw InvalidArgument(std::string(className) + ": missing required parameter '" + name + "'");
    }
```

Comment: We ned to see the code that populates `publicKeyStrHex` and its data. What is `publicKeyStrHex.size()` at the time of the call? I'm guessing the string is empty, `publicKeyStrHex.c_str()` is returning `NULL` and `publicKeyStrHex.size()` is 0. "*`publicKeyStrHex.c_str()` is returning `NULL`"* is not quite correct as you now know :) Try adding a `ASSERT(!publicKeyStrHex.empty())` so the code tells you when there's a problem. You have better things to do with your time than using it to debug programs. Let the tools do the work.

Answer (score -1):

I remember that several years ago, using VS6, I had to deal with the Cyrillic characters, and in that time I had changed the MS-project settings by adding UNICODE in Preprocessor definition ( Project settings -> C/C++) and in the Tab Link I have added an Entry-point symbol: wWinMainCRTStartup.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It didn't help.